# sprintf() garbled output

Tags: c++, printf

I have the following code:

```
char buf[255];
int ID = 0;
double val = 1.234;
sprintf(buf, "%d@%.3lf", ID, val);
printf("%s", buf);
```

`printf()` prints the `ID` value correctly, but the `val` value is just some garbage. Do you know what causes this problem? I am using MSVC 9 on Win7 32-bit. What is even stranger the above code works correctly on a 64-bit machine.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Does using `%.3f` as opposed to `%.3lf` change anything?

Comment: Using %f doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: @PaulR For long double, you need `%Lf`, with an upper case 'L'. ('l' is ignored before an `%f` conversion.)

Comment: Tried it on MSVC9, Win7 32-bit, works fine. Is there some additional code? What happens if you write a console app with only this code?

Comment: Yes, there is some additional code. This code is compiled into a DLL library and actually I have three places where I call the code posted in my question and only in one place it outputs garbage as described.

Comment: used VS2012 and all combinations of f/lf, 32/64, float/double worked fine

Comment: could it be that something else messed up the stack?

Comment: @PaulR: nonsense. `%lf` and `%f` are identical. You're confusing this with `%Lf`, which is for long doubles.

Comment: @Daniel/Kerrek: my bad - posted before coffee - I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2):

after this comment:

Yes, there is some additional code. This code is compiled into a DLL library and actually I have three places where I call the code posted in my question and only in one place in outputs garbage, as described.

This is probably due to some problem elsewhere in your code. You are probably corrupting the stack/heap somewhere and unintentionally overwriting your variable. Check your code with a memory checker (valgrind (unix), CMemLeak(everything))

Comment: I was getting linking time errors when trying to use CMemLeak to check for memory leaks. I've ran my code in loop more than 100000 times and was monitoring memory usage with windows task manager and it seems that memory leakage is not the case. For now I solved the problem by replacing the sprintf with boost::format.

Comment: I didn't say you where leaking memory, you are corrupting the stack/heap. With your quick fix the problem will probably reappear at a later time. What linking errors did you get?

Comment: I get LNK2019 for unresolved XWBReportFinal which I am calling in the destructor of a class which has methods calling 'sprintf'.

Comment: Have you include the CMemLeak header ? and why not use the standard method of including the header in sources that use mallocs ?